# Laravel 8.0 facing issue while trying to update a table with vue form, 'Attempt to read property \"item_id\" on null'

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So, i have a table called Items table and another table called item_quantities, on item_quantities ive a column named item_id which is connected to items table id. All the fillable properties on both  tables are all in one  form on the frontend, and i take care of the form fields on the backend
Whenever i try to update the quantity on the form which is from item_quantities's table with a  form, i'm facing serious issue updating the item_quantities. getting Attempt to read property "item_id" on null.
It all started when i noticed a duplicate entries on the item-quantities table, so i deleted all the datas on it..
Here's is the form screenshot
[The vue form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqyXr.png)

and the backend logic

```
  public function saveData(Request $request, $id) {
    // dd($request->name);
    $updateGroceries = Item::where('id', $request->id)->get()->first();
    $updateGroceries->update([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'price' => $request->price,

    ]);
    if($updateGroceries) {
        $item_quantity = ItemQuantity::where('item_id', $updateGroceries->id) ? 
        ItemQuantity::where('item_id', $updateGroceries->id)->get()->first()  :
        new ItemQuantity;
       
        if($item_quantity->item_id == null) {
            $item_quantity->item_id = $updateGroceries->id;
        }
        $item_quantity->quantity = $request->quantity;
        $item_quantity->save();
       
    }

   
}
```

I'M SO SORRY IF MY ENGLISH WAS'NT CLEARED ENOUGH
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: The problem is with `-get()->first()`, it returns null and error is thrown when trying to access its `item_id` property

Comment: Thats why i conditioned it with ternary operator, if it doesnt find the first then it should instantiate it with a new one. Not sure the condition works

Comment: Can you please post your code as text instead of an image so that your question is still understandable when the image might get deleted in the future?

Comment: okay, thanks for that

Comment: @DipoDeen the condition in your ternary doesn't get executed, it just returns query builder instance and will always be evaluated to true. You might want to execute it with `count` to get number of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`firstOrNew()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models) method. This will first find the item, if not exist create e new instance.

```php
$item_quantity = ItemQuantity::firstOrNew(['item_id' =>  $updateGroceries->id]);
$item_quantity->quantity = $request->quantity;
$item_quantity->save();
```

Note that the model returned by `firstOrNew()` has not yet been persisted to the database. You will need to manually call the `save` method to persist it.

Comment: That's great! Try exploring Laravel documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your errors workflow as that:

```php
$item_quantity=null;
$item_quantity->item_id;
```

You can do that with optional global helper:

```php
optional($item_quantity)->item_id ?: 'default value';
```

Comment: Not familiar with global helper but thanks for your help